# Does unshift mutate the state? How do you tell if the state is mutated (from tools)?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm still new to native and react so I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NuZOwsmzcro) for a todo app and reading the following articles:

- https://lorenstewart.me/2017/01/22/javascript-array-methods-mutating-vs-non-mutating/
- https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/

The addNewTodo method uses unshift which if i'm not mistaken mutates the array/state?

Is there more efficient way to write this with spread on the add method?
Or if I'm completely wrong and its fine, what are good ways to use react tools to figure out if the state is being mutated (say for maintaining other ppl code)?

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      todoInput: '',
      todos: [
        {id: 0, title: 'Insult Jerry', done: false},
        {id: 1, title: 'Build something', done: false},
        {id: 2, title: 'Morty Mind Blowers', done: false}
      ]
    }
  }
  addNewTodo () {
    let todos = this.state.todos;

    todos.unshift({
      id: todos.length + 1,
      title: this.state.todoInput,
      done: false
    });

    this.setState({
      todos,
      todoInput: ''
    });
  }
  toggleDone (item) {
    let todos = this.state.todos;
    todos = todos.map((todo) => {
      if (todo.id == item.id) {
        todo.done = !todo.done;
      }
      return todo;
    })
    this.setState({todos});
  }

  removeTodo (item) {
    let todos = this.state.todos;
    todos = todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== item.id);
    this.setState({todos});
  }
...
```

Comment: Yes, `unshift` mutates the state. You can take a copy of the `todos` and `unshift` that array. And then use it in `setState`

Comment: Or use spread `this.setState({ todos: [...this.state.todos, { id: .., title: .., done: false }], .. })` Not necessarily "more efficient" though.

Comment: BTW, `toggleDone` is also mutating the state because of `todo.done = !todo.done`

Comment: @HereticMonkey - `unshift` adds to the beginning rather than the end

Comment: @madebydavid Good point; good thing it's a comment and not an answer :). Main point is that it's not necessarily more efficient.

Comment: Yeah, not sure about the requirement to be efficient, I would say understandability was the most important.

Comment: The main reason I asked this is kinda what ppl are discussing. I personally find the spread, map, etc more confusing than mutating methods. But I also get how its important from the second article linked above. IDK why though...

Comment: What tools do you use most for finding out if another developer is mutating the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the spread operator instead of `unshift` like this:

```
this.setState({
  todos: [
    {
      id: this.state.todos.length + 1,
      title: this.state.todoInput,
      done: false
    },
    ...this.state.todos
  ]
});
```

I'm not aware of any tools which allow you to figure out if the state is being mutated. But if you're up for using TypeScript you can declare the state as `readonly` to prevent this type of mutation.

Comment: That works well. 

So this adds to the end
`
    this.setState({
      todos: [
        ...this.state.todos,
        {...}
      ]
    });
`
while this adds to the begining:
`
    this.setState({...},
        ...this.state.todos
      ]
    });
`